# Cypress y Gherkin - Como realizar todo un test con un conjunto de datos

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

Tengo una prueba en gherkin, y quiero usar un set de datos para ejecutar todo el test, no solo uno de los pasos, pero no encuentro una forma correcta de hacerlo. ( Estoy usando cypress con js )

En el ejemplo siguiente, en el paso **El usuario completa su dni** , en Gherkin defino una tabla con dnis (son numeros unicos de identificacion del cliente) mientras que en Js los recibo con un dataTable e itero sobre ellos para realizar la acción, pero esto permite que con la tabla realize solo la acción dentro del paso: `homePage.getInputDNI().type(row.dni)` , cuando lo que yo realmente busco es que con dicha tabla, se realizen todos los pasos del test, desde el primer When hasta el ultimo Then.

¿Para ello quizás no debería definirlo a través de una tabla, pero entonces cual sería la forma correcta de realizarlo?

Por ejemplo: (En el archivo gherkin)

```
Feature: Pruebas en test Ahorro Seguro - Pagina Consulta

Background:
    Given El usuario ingresa a la web
    When La url es la correspondiente
    Then Pasa a completar su DNI

Scenario: El cliente esta permitido cotizar
When El usuario completa su DNI
|dni|
|19725089|
|18726087|
Then Pasa a la pagina de Verificacion De Datos

When Se valida los tipos de dato de los inputs
And Completa los datos solicitados
Then Pasa a la pagina de Cotizacion

y siguen los pasos ...
```

En js:

```
Given('El usuario ingresa a la web',()=>{
    cy.visit('/',{failOnStatusCode: false})
});

When('La url es la correspondiente',()=>{
    homePage.getUrl().should('contains','nombre de la pagina')
})

Then('Pasa a completar su DNI',()=>{ // codigo })

When('El usuario completa su DNI',(dataTable)=>{
    dataTable.hashes().forEach(row=>{
        homePage.getInputDNI().type(row.dni)
    })
});

Then('Pasa a la pagina de Verificacion De Datos',()=>{
    // codigo
})

When('Se valida los tipos de dato de los inputs',()=>{
    // codigo
})

And('Completa los datos solicitados',()=>{
    // codigo
})

Then('Pasa a la pagina de Cotizacion',()=>{
    // codigo
})
```